# Insert string or character in Linked-list C

Tags: c, string, function, linked-list, char

I'd like to understand how to store correctly a certain string into linked list.

For example the list is defined :

```
typedef struct node {
int code;
char surname[n];
struct node *next;
}Student;
typedef Student *List;
```

Is the definition correct ?

Or should i insert a pointer to a char ? for example `char *pc` ?

The question is how to store the surname properly, if i had to insert a value into 'code' it is relatively simple because i simply for example declare a pointer 'aux' and then aux->code = x, where x is an integer.

The problem is how to scan or how to put a string of characters into the surname[n] place,for example calling a function.

For example creating an other vector of size n,vet[n] scan this one and then assign `aus->surname  = vet[n]` will work?

An other info, maybe related with the first question, could the size of the array defined into the struct be variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you define it `n` needs to be a compile-time-constant; so - regarding the last part of the question - `n` cannot vary from object to object and hence makes no sense in the `struct` itself.

The difference between `*surname` and `surname[n]` is that you need to allocate memory for it using `malloc`, whereas the latter provides the memory within each object. Both will work; However, assigning an array will not work in neither case:

```
char* surname;
...
char vec[100];
scanf("%99s",vec);
surname = malloc(strlen(vec)+1);
strcpy(surname,vec);
```

Don't forget to `free` surname once the object shall be discarded.

or:

```
char surname[100];
...
char vec[100];
scanf("%99s",vec);
strcpy(surname,vec);
```